# How to remove the last item in the list(Of) in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a windows form application which added string into list of collection. This can be done by input the string into the textbox then click 'add' button, and the list will display in a listbox. 
Now, I want to delete the **last item** in the list collection & the listbox.

Below are the code snippett that I have done

```
  Public strList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    'add string to list
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TxtBox.Text <> "" Then
            strList.Add(TxtBox.Text)
            TxtBox.Clear()
        End If

        lstItem.Items.Clear()
        strList.ForEach(AddressOf ListItem)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        lstItem.Items.Clear()
        strList.ForEach(AddressOf ListItem)
    End Sub

    'Add item into list
    Public Sub ListItem(s As String)
        lstItem.Items.Add(s)
        'lstItem.Sorted = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        strList.ToList.ForEach(AddressOf DeleteItem)

    End Sub

    'Delete item

    Public Sub DeleteItem(s As String)
        For i = 0 To strList.Count
            lstItem.Items.RemoveAt(strList.Count - 1)
            i = i + 1
        Next

    End Sub
```

as you can see, in the sub **DeleteItem**, i try to delete the last item of the list collection by clicking 'delete button'. but the error says *Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.*

can anyone help me on this? thank you.

Comment: You are looping over number of items in `strList`, but removing items in `lstItem` - what makes you think that they are have the same number of items? And you're not removing only the last item - you are removing the `n` last items depending on the number of items in `strList`.

Comment: Don't do `i = i + 1`, the `For` loop already does that for you so now you're incrementing `i` _twice_. Though if you only want to remove the one last item, you shouldn't use a loop at all. Remove the loop and just keep `lstItem.Items.RemoveAt(strList.Count - 1)`.

Comment: parameter s was for previous condition. it's my bad for not noticing it @Caramiriel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really ought to do is use a `BindingList(Of String)` and bind it to the `ListBox`.  That way, you only have to deal with one list.  Adding and removing against the underlying `BindingList` will automatically affect the `ListBox`:

```
Private items As New BindingList(Of String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListBox1.DataSource = items
End Sub

Private Sub addButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addButton.Click
    items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub deleteSelectedButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles deleteSelectedButton.Click
    items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub deleteLastButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles deleteLastButton.Click
    items.RemoveAt(items.Count - 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: This way it works perfectly. but does that mean BindingList is available in listBox only? what if I wanted to display it in a textbox instead?

Comment: What I have found is that, textboxes cannot be included as bindingList. the datasource is not available for that. However, is there a way I can do this using textbox field?

Comment: No, you haven't found that at all, because that is nonsensical.  Not surprisingly, a `BindingList(Of T)` is like a `List(Of T)` but with functionality specific to binding.  Stop trying to make things more complicated than they are.  I've shown you how to bind, add and remove items, which is all you need to address the issue you asked about here.  If you have another issue, post a new question about that specifically.

Comment: Well, thank you for the superb explanation, sir. :-)